# Solving for upper limit of integration, given a lower limit and integrand

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider $f$ a real integrable function, usually we want to evaluate the integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ for some $a<b$ given. Now, suppose we know $a$ but we don't know $b$, further, we know the value of this integral, let $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lambda$. My question is, in what conditions we can find $b$, and how?

A simple case is when $f$ has a known primitive $F$ and $F$ has inverse $F^{-1}$.
$$ \int_a^bf(x)dx=\lambda\implies F(b)-F(a)=\lambda\implies F(b)=F(a)+\lambda\implies b=F^{-1}(F(a)+\lambda)$$

In this case we can evaluate $b$, but if this is not the case, what can be done?

Thanks.

PS: More approaches are welcome, approaches not relying on $f$ primitive.

Comment: You've outlined a solution when $F$, an antiderivative of $f$, is known explicitly enough to give the expression for $b$ you gave.  Are you asking about conditions for $F$ to have an inverse?  Or about methods for numerical solution when no "symbolic form" of $F$ is available (or if available, not useful)?

Comment: @hardmath I don't think he's asking that. I think he wants to be able to find $b$ even if $F$ isn't invertible.

Comment: @Integral The same way $F$ needn't be invertible, there might be more than one $b$ such that $\int \limits_a^bf$ equals a certain constant. Just think of periodic functions.

Comment: @GitGud: For the sake of completeness, even if $F$ is invertible there might be less than one $b$...

Comment: Its possible to have no $b$ or more than one $b$ as solution, I'm aware of that. Would be good to have a method to identify this and give the solutions when they exist.

Comment: And if possible, to avoid to talk about $F$, go directly to $b$.

Comment: I did this topic to know if there is some results about this anywhere.

Comment: Of course numerical solutions are welcome! They interest me too.

Comment: You know what time you left and the total distance covered by your trip. It requires a lot more information on how the trip went to know what time you arrived if you don't have a clock.

Comment: If I understand well, the clock is the function $f$. We have it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how satisfying it will be, but the work you've shown in your Question proves that talk about which $b$ attains which $\lambda$ is equivalent to talk about a specific antiderivative $F$ attaining values $\lambda$, namely the antiderivative of $f$ such that $F(a) = 0$.  Since all antiderivatives of $f$ are obtained by adding the famous "+C" to any one of them, the latter constraint can always be arranged (provided the function $f$ is integrable on a suitable interval containing $a$).

The issue is whether solutions exist, and how to find them:

$$ F(b) = \lambda $$

Conceivably $f$ will be given in a form that we can easily evaluate, but expressions for $F$ are not available or are not easily evaluated.  In such cases we are apt to fall back on [numerical integration schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) to try and show solutions exists and narrow down the approximation of them.

The best "quadrature rule" depends on the smoothness of $f$ and on what precision is needed in locating $b$.  Knowing that $F$ is increasing where $f$ is positive and decreasing where $f$ is negative, we can use knowledge of the sign of $f$ to help bracket intervals that might contain solutions $b$.  Indeed, since the derivative of $F$ is simply $f$, using [root finding methods that exploit derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is apt to make refining precision of approximate solutions go that much faster.

Comment: I had some hope that would be some possible to evaluate $b$ without computing $F$. But not the numerical method. I don't know...looks like finding $b$ is easier then solving a integral.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying:

> A simple case is when $f$ has primitive $F$ and $F$ has inverse $F^{-1}$

The first part of this is the same thing as saying that $f$ is integrable. Then we have the primitive defined by $F\left(x\right)=\int_{a}^{x}f\left(y\right)dy$. Here we also have $F(a)=0$ and in fact you are looking for solutions $b$ of the equation:

$F(b)=\lambda$.

I don't exclude that only the second part of the quote was meant to be mentioned as relevant.

Comment: It is possible to integrate $f$ (real function) when we don't know it's primitive. We can use series, numerical methods, residue, and many other stuff. I'm interested in what we can do to find $b$ when we don't have the primitive of $f$.

Comment: If I understand you well then what you meant to say was: A simple case is when $f$ has a *known* primitive $F$ and $F$ has inverse $F^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes. I just showed this case as an illustration, I'm looking for another approaches.