# How to find the height of sand in an hourglass?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

EDIT: I have made an important correction to the "previous question" link below... it was accidentally pointing to an unrelated question before.

I would also like to emphasize that I welcome any completely different approach to the question (solving for height as a function of "P") -- not just a correction to/extension of my potentially flawed approach... the simpler the better, of course.

Also, I'm realizing that it's unclear whether I'm asking for a general solution for any shape that conforms to the described properties, or whether I'm asking for a specific, perhaps more elegant, solution specifically for the lemniscate of Bernoulli... or thirdly, for help completing my specific attempt at a solution.  I am interested in all those things, so, honestly I don't really know what to do about that other than to break the question up into multiple separate questions.  Hopefully it's OK as is.

---

Let's say we have an hourglass/"container-type" shape that when viewed in 2 dimensions is both horizontally and vertically symmetrical around its center... with its 3-dimensional "counterpart" being radially symmetric around its vertical axis.  I have chosen the lemniscate of Bernoulli:

[image]

We imagine the "top" half is "full" of "sand" -- or some imaginary substance that has a perfectly level surface.

Anyway, given that some percentage of the sand, P, has fallen to the bottom, how can we calculate the height of that sand as a function of P?

[image]

So that is the basic question.  It's been years since the calculus days (assuming the answer can't be found an easier way), and I have spend days getting extremely confused by this.

---

**My attempt at an answer and the reasoning for it:**

Apparently it is true that it makes no difference if we use a 2 or 3-dimensional world in which to make this calculation (I have verified this with a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464986/is-the-height-of-sand-as-a-function-of-time-any-different-between-a-2d-hourglass)).

Further, since the shape is symmetrical, we can literally, cut this problem in half by plotting half of the lemniscate in the following way (in fact, we probably only need a quarter of it):

[image]

Setting a = 1:

[image]

Because we have cut the problem in half, for our purposes now, the the total amount of sand is equal to one quarter the area of the original lemniscate -- the area under the curve of the above function on the interval (0,sqrt(2)):

[image]

This area = 0.5 because the area of a lemniscate is:

Area squared = 2 * a squared. (and a=1 as established already).

So let's say some amount of sand has fallen:

[image]

Now, we *should* be able to find the height, s, of that percent, P, of the sand in the bottom half... by [solving for the upper limit of integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579521/solving-for-upper-limit-of-integration-given-a-lower-limit-and-integrand) of:

[image]

Where f(x) is the "y =" function shown earlier.

However I'm stuck here because I can't find the integral of that function, presumably because it's not possible?  I tried using integral-calculator.com and it says it's not possible.

**To summarize, my general approach (for any shape) is:**

1. Establish a "f(x)" function representing half of the shape in its horizontal orientation
2. Calculate the "total area of sand"
3. For a given percentage of sand that has fallen, solve for the height of sand by using a limit of integration.

More importantly, though, *I'm sure there is a better way to do this whole problem*... maybe an ultra-simple geometric way exists for the lemniscate due to its unique properties?

Comment: Have you tried using polar coordinates instead of Cartesian?

Comment: "Apparently it is true that it makes no difference if we use a 2 or 3-dimensional world in which to make this calculation". But result will be not the same for 2D and 3D calculation.

Comment: Integral of $f(x)$ cannot be expressed in closed form, that does not mean that it does not exist. In 3D world with the same shape you will have integral of $f(x)^2$ which can be expressed in closed form. But equation $\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^s f(x)^2\,dx=A$ cannot be solved for $s$ in closed form. Therefore you will require numerical calculation anyway.

Comment: If $P\in [0,.25*(total area)]$ is known, then you have $P = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^s f(x)dx$. If an antiderivative of $f$ exists, say $F(x)$, then the equation becomes, $F(s) = P+F(-\sqrt{2})$ by FTC. Then, further assuming $F$ to be invertible would allow you to solve for $s$.

Comment: Substituting $v=a^4+4a^2x^2$ into $\int y(x) dx$ gets you this [simple closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+-%28-3+a%5E2+%2B+sqrt%28a%5E4%2B4a%5E2x%5E2%29%29%5E2%2F%288+a%5E2+sqrt%28%283+a%5E2+-+sqrt%28a%5E4%2B4a%5E2x%5E2%29%29%2F%28a%5E2+%2B+sqrt%28a%5E4%2B4a%5E2x%5E2%29%29%29%29). What is the relation between $y$ and $f(x)$? See the “alternate forms” section of the link.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu so are you saying that is false?  That is rather important so please visit and correct the linked question's answer if you have time!!

Comment: @NerdyBunz: Answer of lonza leggiera is correct for 3D-world (when hourglass has volume), because of using formula $V=\int \pi r(h)^2 \, dh$. But this answer is not correct for flat hourglass which is not rotation body but extrusion body with the same shape. I supposed that in your 2D case you've meant flat hourglass, where $V=a \int w(h) \,dh$, where $a$ is thickness, $w(h)$ is width at height $h$.

Comment: By "linked question" I meant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464986/is-the-height-of-sand-as-a-function-of-time-any-different-between-a-2d-hourglass

Comment: You have misunderstood the answer to the linked question. It was all about the 3D hourglass the whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume the hourglass is obtained by rotating the lemniscate about its axis of symmetry ($x$ axis).
The volume of sand in the lower part is then
$$
V=\int_{\sqrt2-h}^{\sqrt2}\pi y^2\,dx,
$$
where $h$ is the height of sand. Hence:
$$
P={\int_{\sqrt2-h}^{\sqrt2}\pi y^2\,dx
\over
\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}\pi y^2\,dx}.
$$

Comment: I suppose that you enjoy practicing self-mockery. I like it (as well as your answer). $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This is just to show the OP that a "3D" solution can be simpler than a "2D" one.

Comment: This, for sure. I was speaking about your user name. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks! I think I might understand this! :). Is it supposed to be trivial to solve for h now? Is that what Claude Leibovici is doing in his answer?  PS - I've made some important edits to the question.

Comment: @NerdyBunz The integrals can be computed (see Claude Leibovici's answer) but expressing $h$ as a function of $P$ is impossible using elementary function.

Answer (score 2):

@Intelligenti pauca gave the solution and
$$\int \big[-(1+t^2)+\sqrt{4 t^2+1}\big]\,dt=-t-\frac{1}{3}t^3+\frac{1}{2}t \sqrt{4 t^2+1} +\frac{1}{4} \sinh ^{-1}(2 t)$$ Computing the definite integrals we have
$$\left(3 \sinh ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right)-2 \sqrt{2}\right)\,P=$$
$$-4 h^3+12 \sqrt{2} h^2+6 \left(\sqrt{4 h \left(h-2 \sqrt{2}\right)+9}-6\right) h+$$ $$3
   \left(-2 \sqrt{8 h \left(h-2 \sqrt{2}\right)+18}+6 \sqrt{2}+\sinh ^{-1}\left(2
   \sqrt{2}\right)\right)-3 \sinh ^{-1}\left(2 \left(\sqrt{2}-h\right)\right)$$ which cannot be inversed. However, you could have a good approximation of it using an empirical model such as
$$h=\frac {\sum_{k=1}^m a_k \,P^k}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \,P^k}$$ For example, with $m=n=3$, $R^2>0.999999$, all paremeters being highly significant. The maximum absolute error is $0.003328$ and the mean error is $0.000020$.

Just make the regression.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately this answer is beyond my comprehension -- I don't know what these equations are based upon or where "t" came from (I don't recommend explaining it).  Are you basically saying I should use Riemann sums to find the area under the curve?  PS - I've made some important edits to the question also.

Comment: Looking at the "2d" graph in my question, why could I not simply use Reimann sums  of two-dimensional rectangles to get the same result?